# How to avoid Singularity in numerical integration

Tags: matlab, integral, numerical-integration

I want to numerically integrate the following with Matlab:

```matlab
fun = @(t) (((1 - (-1)^n * cos(n*pi*t/R))) ./ t);
hn = integral(fun, 0, (sqrt(R^2 - x^2)));
```

For now, I just avoided to evaluate the integral in 0, are they any way to encounter the singularity at this point.

Comment: If `n` is even, the function does _not_ have a singularity at 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `eps` instead of `0` as the lower limit in your `integral`, I guess then you can also make it

```matlab
R=101; 
X=linspace(0,R,1001)';
for n=1:10 
    for c=1:length(X) 
        x=X(c); 
        fun=@(t) (((1 - (-1)^n*cos(n*pi*sqrt(t.^2+x.^2)/R)))./sqrt(t.^2+x.^2)); 
        hn(c,n) = integral(fun,eps,(sqrt(R^2-x^2))); 
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It doesn't help to solve the problem

Comment: @user11822932 Could you show the difference of with or without dealing with the singularity? Otherwise it is not clear only through your description

Comment: R=101;   
X=linspace(0,R,1001)'
for n=1:10
    
for c=1:length(X)
        x=X(c);
fun=@(t) (((1 - (-1)^n*cos(n*pi*sqrt(t.^2+x.^2)/R)))./sqrt(t.^2+x^2));


 hn(c,n) = integral(fun,0,(sqrt(R^2-x^2)));
end
   end
This is the code when i'am dealing with singularity ( in this case i have the folowing warning :Reached the limit on the maximum number of intervals in use)
Once i change the inner for loop to for c=1:lenght(x)-1 x=X(c+1) i'm avoiding the singularity but i'm ignoring the evaluation of the integral at x=0;

Comment: @user11822932 please see my updated solution. The function `integral` cannot circumvent singularity, such that you need to play some trick to avoid it manually...

Comment: It gives quite the same thing, i slightly modified the denominateur as follow 
1/sqrt(t^2+epqilon^2+x^2) to avoid singularity.

Comment: Absolutely, since `integral` cannot predict where the singularity is, so it should be treated manually when it is known mathematically...